# Trigger.io: Anyway to pre-load the HTML for the forge.tabs.openWithOptions()

Tags: html, iframe, tabs, trigger.io

We are displaying our Ads using `forge.tabs.openWithOptions`, but the problem is the user can quickly close the tabs even if the content inside the tabs not yet finished loading. So the whole Ad System became not usable and we can't be able to earn to it.

Is it possible to pre-load the html url even though the tabs was not yet shown? Or can we disable the close button for a certain amount of time to force the user to view the ads?

Waiting for your response, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using an iframe to display your ads? This may give you more control over how they are loaded and displayed.

Comment: nope, our plan is to display it on child browser so that users can close/stay on the ads wall list. The problem is the user can close immediately even though the html content was not even loaded. So it is possible to put a certain time for which we can disable the close button?

Comment: If you show the ad with an iframe you can make it fill the whole webview and have complete control of how long it appears for. It is not possible to disable the close button using the child browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, caching will not do the trick as the ads content changes everytime. Having said this, your best bet would be to somehow disable the close button of forge.tabs. This is most probably only possible by implementing your own custom forge.tabs using [native modules](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what is the connection of opening the url using get and opening it again using forge.tabs?

Comment: I just thought it might be cached after you retrieved it using request.get. However you're probably right that this won't work the way I thought. Another try: What about loading the page in an iframe that is positioned outside of the viewport to make it 'invisible'. Sounds pretty hacky but might achieve a preloading effect.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah...it's a bit hacky. The problem with my url is that its content is changing everytime. The URL is an Ad URL that generates an Ad Wall. So caching seems impossible because we need the latest contents to be displayed in forge.tabs. Is it possible to disable our close button by a certain amount of time which is set at the options when calling the tabs?